# Rotating caption with image using a custom float

Tags: floats, captions, rotating

How do you rotate a caption with the image in a custom float?

I've tried the savebox and rotcaption methods outlined in this [topic](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46329/landscape-caption-for-a-rotated-figure-in-a-portrait-page). My image rotates 90 degrees but my caption stays untouched and remains underneath the picture when it should rotate along with the image. Here is the code.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{rotate}

\floatstyle{plain}
\floatname{example}{Example}
\newfloat{example}{h}{lop}

\begin{document}

\newsavebox{\myimage}

\begin{example}
    \centering
    \savebox{\myimage}{\rule{100pt}{150pt}}%
    \rotatebox{90}{%
        \begin{minipage}{\wd\myimage}
            \includegraphics{picture1.jpg}
            \caption{Here is the caption for this picture}
        \end{minipage}}
\end{example}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you want to use a landscape page ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If using the [`newfloat`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/newfloat) package (instead of `float`) to define your custom float is an option, then your method works and also the mechanism offered by the [`hvfloat`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/hvfloat) package:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{newfloat}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hvfloat}

\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[name=Example,placement=htbp,fileext=lop]{example}

\begin{document}

Some reference text

\newsavebox{\myimage}

\begin{example}
\centering
\savebox{\myimage}{\rule{100pt}{150pt}}%
\rotatebox{90}{%
  \begin{minipage}{\wd\myimage}
  \centering            
  \includegraphics[width=100pt]{ctanlion}
  \caption{Here is the caption for this picture}
  \label{ex;test2}
  \end{minipage}}
\end{example}

\hvFloat[rotAngle=90,capWidth=w]%
  {example}%
  {\includegraphics[width=100pt]{ctanlion}}%
  {Here is the caption for this picture}%
  {ex:test2}

\end{document}
```

[image]

CTAN lion drawing by Duane Bibby.

Adding the option `within=<counter>|none` to `\DeclareFloatingEnvironment`, you can specify the counter which will be used to reset the counter of the
floating environment. For example, `within=none` will result in a continuous numbering throughout the document.

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly. Any way to change the numeration in the caption? It is showing the chapter and the figure number, i.e: Example 5.1 instead of Example 1.

Comment: @Jacob you can add the option `within=none` to `\DeclareFloatingEnvironment`, as in `\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[name=Example,placement=htbp,fileext=lop,within=none]{example}`. Please don't forget to accept my answer if you consider that it solved your problem (in case of doubt, please see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852/3954).)