# Rotate image in LaTeX

Tags: graphics, rotating, wide-image

I would like to rotate an image (in LATEX) keeping it at the same location (I just want to rotate it) In order to do that I used `\begin{sidewaysfigure}[H]`  but is not working.

The current output: **The image appears on the last sheets**

what's going on?  any idea? I also changed the **height/widht** but it doesn't work either:

```
\begin{sidewaysfigure}[H]
 \includegraphics{image}
 \caption{Swimlane Diagram.}
%\label{swim}
\end{sidewaysfigure}
```

Comment: From the package documentation of `rotating`: "two new environments, `sidewaystable` and `sidewaysfigure`, each of which produces a single page-size float with contents rotated ±90 degrees"  Please clarify: Do you want to keep the rotated image on the same page as other unrotated content or do you want the image to be on a single page, but stay where it was used in the code?

Comment: Hard to say without seeing the image and an example document, but my guess is that `\begin{figure}[H] ... \includegraphics[angle=90]{whatever} ... ` would achieve the result you need.

Comment: I don't think sideways figure supports [H].  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/262816/i-want-my-rotated-figure-captions-to-be-facing-outwards/262853?r=SearchResults&s=1|30.0036#262853  and ignore the -90 version.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can save the figure + caption in a box and then rotate the box, or use the `sidewaysfigure` environment from the `rotating` package. It puts the figure on its own page. For a small figure you can use the `\rotcaption` command to rotate the caption.

[image]

[image]

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{caption}
    \captionsetup{font=small,labelfont=bf}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{rotating}

\newsavebox{\savefig}
\begin{document}

Save the figure + caption in a box and rotate
\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \centering
    \savebox{\savefig}{\rule{8cm}{5cm}}
    \rotatebox{90}{%
        \begin{minipage}{\wd\savefig}
            \usebox{\savefig}
            \caption{Swimlane Diagram}
        \end{minipage}}
\end{figure}

Just rotate the caption
\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \hfill
    \rule{5cm}{8cm}%
    \hspace{\abovecaptionskip}%
    \begin{minipage}[b][8cm][c]{2\baselineskip}
        \rotcaption{Just rotate caption}
    \end{minipage}
    \hfill\mbox{}
\end{figure}

Use the sidewaysfigure environment
\begin{sidewaysfigure}
    \centering
    \rule{15cm}{10cm}
    \caption{A sideways figure}
\end{sidewaysfigure}

\end{document}**
```

Taken from --https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/46337/197451

Comment: which one is figure name? :D

Answer (score 19):

You can define the angle property in \includegraphics:

```
\begin{figure}[h]
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth, angle=90]{c.jpg}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: keep in mind that this rotates the image from the corner, not from the center (which is more natural in my opinion). For the latter, add `,origin=c`

Comment: Works like a charm. Keep in mind, that after rotating width=\textwidth still references the original width of the figure, not the "new" width after rotating.